# Remove groupby and optimize the pandas code

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace for loop to gain more performance in pandas. Using for loop in pandas is performance killer, read it in many blogs. Right now, I have to apply a some logic to set of items and group by `emp_id`. the chunk of code is below. Right now, below code works, however the complaints are related to performance. I can't remove `groupby` for sure, is there any other technique I can use to gain more performance ?

```
     emp_groups = self.df.groupby("emp_id")
     for key, item in emp_groups: 
         for _ridx in range(0, len(self.rules), 2):
           # logic on item
```

`_ridx` - is set of rules, which are applied to group of columns.

Comment: what's the significance of `_ridx` here?

Comment: I have two rules to each column in item. Basically, there is a rule, I want to know which employee data grouped by emp_id matches thoserule.

Comment: @QuangHoang - removing that for loop might be easy, does it helps in performance?

Comment: I modified the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `item` in the grouped object is just a `DataFrame`, so you can vectorize your logic if possible and combine with the `agg` function to speed things up - for example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 400], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'C': [3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1]})
gdf = df.groupby('A')
def f1(gdf):
    for key, item in gdf:
        return item.sum()

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('f1(gdf)', globals=globals(), number=10000)) #~8s
print(timeit.timeit('gdf.agg(np.sum)', globals=globals(), number=10000)) #~5s
```